# UILabel.text is not working when app is minimized, phone is lock and app open from callkit use password(Without password works fine)

Tags: swift

My app includes call functionality
when my app is minimized and phone is lock and call came it shows callkit and from callkit if I open my application than it shows blank screen I have changed mylabel text value but it is not showing

But if my phone is not having any passcode than it is working perfactly

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the text of the UILabel on the main thread.

Use dispatch queues

Comment: Hi Raj thanks for reply but I've used dispatch queue with main but it is not working